# curve_fit can not do a linear fit

Tags: python-2.7, curve-fitting, curve

I have a pretty simple data which the curve_fit can not give me a linear fit to it. 
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
#################
def linear(x,a,b):
    return a*x+b
#################
N=[200,250,300,400,500,600,700]
sp=[17,18,20,23,26,28,31]
tp=[19,21.5,23.5,27,30,33,36]
#################
error=[0]*len(N)
for i in range(len(N)):
      error[i]=abs(sp[i]-tp[i])/(1.0*sp[i])*100
a,b=curve_fit(linear,N,error)
print a
plt.figure()
plt.plot(N,error,'r-o',label=r'${\rm relative\ error}$')
plt.plot(N,linear(N,*a))
plt.grid()
plt.savefig('error.pdf')
plt.show()
```

and what I get is none sense:
  [none sense result!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ICe4V.png)
What is going on

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `linear` is maybe not the best as `N` is a list and `a` is about zero. it should work if you call `plt.plot( N, linear( np.array( N ),*a ) )` instead.
Moreover I highly recommend to rename the variables as `curve_fit` returns an array of best values and the covariance matrix. Hence `bestFit, pcov = curve_fit( linear, N, error )` and then `plt.plot( N, linear( np.array( N ), *bestFit ) )` is probably better and avoids confusion. `a, b = ( curve_fit( linear, N, error) )[0]` might work though but then you'd have to pass `plt.plot( N, linear( np.array( N ), a, b ) )`

Eventually, I'd do it like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
#################
def linear( x, a, b):
    return a * x + b
#################
N =  np.array([ 200, 250, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700 ], np.float )
sp = np.array([ 17, 18, 20, 23, 26, 28, 31 ], np.float )
tp = np.array([ 19, 21.5, 23.5, 27, 30, 33, 36 ], np.float )
#################
error = np.fromiter( ( abs( s - t ) / s * 100 for s, t in zip( sp, tp ) ), np.float)
bestFit, pcov = curve_fit( linear, N, error )
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot( 1, 1, 1 )
ax.plot( N, error, 'r-o', label=r'${\rm relative\ error}$' )
ax.plot( N,  linear( N, *bestFit ) )
ax.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: All OK]

So, works as it should.